# BootstrapDialog Alert in Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-dialog

I want to use bootstrapDialog alert (https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) instead of default alertbox of browser in my controller but its not working.

I included these scripts I got from the [github dist](https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/tree/master/dist) folder in the bottom of view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" />
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```

**Controller**

```
function student(){

  if ($student_status == 'paid'){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'BootstrapDialog.alert('Your Registration was successful')';
    echo '</script>';
  }
 else {
    //  redirect url
  }
}
```

I also tried to echo the css and js files in the controller but failed. If I echo the default alertbox, it works, please what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap dialog is built on Bootstrap, so you must include bootstrap css and bootstrap js, followed by the bootstrapDialog css and js

```
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mreis1/YJdB7/1/

**For Example**

**View:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.1/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.1/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>

  <title>Bootstrap Dialog Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- IF SUCCESSFUL -->
<?php $alert= ''; ?>
<?php   if ($alert == 'success'): ?>

<script type = "text/javascript">
BootstrapDialog.alert('Your Registration was Successful');
</script>

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- IF FAILED -->

<?php   if($alert == 'failed'): ?>

<script type = "text/javascript">
BootstrapDialog.alert({
            title: 'An Error Occured',
            message: 'Your Registration failed',
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
            buttonLabel: 'Close'

        });

</script>
<?php endif; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```
function student(){

  if ($student_status == 'paid'){
    $data['alert'] = 'success';
  }
 else {
    $data['alert'] = 'failed';
  }
  $this->load->view(view_page, $data);
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Success Alert]

[image: Failed Alert]

Answer (score 2):

**first - you have some errors:**

- you need to escape your single quotes of the alert like:

  ```
  echo 'BootstrapDialog.alert(\'Your Registration was successful\')';
  ```

  or you could use mix of single and double quotes like:

  ```
  echo 'BootstrapDialog.alert("Your Registration was successful")';
  ```
- you also might need to load your script and css with a leading slash like:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" />
  <script src="/assets/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
  ```
- you are loading your stylesheet as script, `<script src="assets/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css"></script>;` is incorrect, use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="your.css">`

**second -** its not a good idea to mix javascript and php the way you do it, you cannot call a jquery function from php, you can only generate html, which then executes at runtime. This would work:

```
  if ($student_status == 'paid'){
    $str='  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
           <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.1/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
               setTimeout(function() { 
                  BootstrapDialog.alert(\'Your Registration was successful\') 
               },10);
           </script>';
    echo $str;
  }
```

note the `setTimout()` function, it is needed to give a little time to make sure all your files are loaded.

**third -** The correct way is to use ajax instead: see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

- jquery ajax calls your php function student.
- function student returns true or false.
- In the ajax success callback you add your bootstrapDialog.alert

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "BootstrapDialog.alert('Your Registration was successful')"
```

You have to either escape quotes or use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" />
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
```